# Setting up a donation button

Tags: ee2, ecommerce, paypal

I want to have a donation button on my site and I was wondering if anyone had any experience using anything that they could suggest to use or not to use like paypal. I have seen some stuff I could buy and was wondering if I had to go this route or if there was a different route. I want something that would protect the people donating of course and not sure if there is something I need to add to provide an extra layer of protection or not. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: This seems off topic. Questions on ExpressionEngine® Answers - Stack Exchange are expected to relate to ExpressionEngine within the scope defined in the [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an EE question but it's an easy one...

Use Paypal buttons. Very easy to set up, just copy/paste the code Paypal generates into a template and you're done... unless there is a specific reason you don't want to use Paypal. Your question mentions something "like paypal" but doesn't say you don't want to use Paypal.

Comment: I'm fine with paypal, I just didn't know if EE had any kind of alternative that people suggest or anything like that. Thank you for your help. This forum has been super helpful in helping me with my first website.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much use whatever service you like. For many nonprofits, we rotate between: [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com), [Network for Good](http://www1.networkforgood.org), [JustGive](https://www.justgive.org), [Razoo](http://www.razoo.com), and [Amazon Donations](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/asp/donations) and custom set-ups.

The biggest issue is how much you want to customize and control vs how quickly you want the user to be in and out of the process. Faster process means, the potential donor is less likely to abandon, services like PayPal, Network for Good, Razoo, JustGive work well, and people trust them (mostly). Some are more popular than others, so the trust level may vary.

Custom solutions are always the tricky component, because generally the nonprofit wants as much data as possible and the potential donor wants to give as little data as possible, so a direct conflict of interest to a degree.

You can use just a donate button and jump people to PayPal, or EE's Simple Commerce or Exp:resso's Store to handle donations if you expect to process a fair number of them. Something like Store will give you a dashboard to manage donations and better tracking capabilities even if people give anonymously.

But if you just need a simple, quick, 'Donate' or 'Donate Now' button, any of the services will do, because very little is handled in EE. Just the template that the button will go on and possible a pop-up or overlay button telling people that the transaction will be handled by whichever vendor you select.